# Issues with ncurses, menu.h, and current_item()

Tags: c++, c, menu, ncurses, curses

I'm having trouble with menus in ncurses. I'm trying to set up a menu, have the user select an option, and set an int called `num_players` depending upon their selection.
I do this with `boost::lexical_cast` and `item_name(current_item(my_menu))` but every time I call `current_item(my_menu)` I'm just getting `NULL`.
Here's a sample of the code in question:

```
char *choices[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
    //create the dynamic array for the items and their description
    ITEM** my_items;
    MENU *my_menu;
    int num_choices = 6;
    my_items = new ITEM*;
    for (int x = 0; x < num_choices; x++)
    {
       my_items[x] = new_item(choices[x], choices[x]); 
    }
    my_items[6] = (ITEM*)NULL;
    my_menu = new_menu((ITEM**)my_items);
    set_menu_mark(my_menu, " * ");
    set_current_item(my_menu, my_items[0]);
    post_menu(my_menu);
    wrefresh(scr);

    int c;
    while((c = wgetch(scr)) != '\n')
    {   switch(c)
        {   case KEY_DOWN:
                menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
                break;
        }
    }
    //right here, calling current_item just gives me null
    //am I supposed to unpost the menu first?
    //what am I doing wrong? this is frustrating
    ITEM* cur = current_item(my_menu);
    setNumPlayers((char*) item_name(cur));
    unpost_menu(my_menu);
    free_item(my_items[0]);
    free_item(my_items[1]);
    free_item(my_items[2]);
    //etc etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:

```
my_items = new ITEM*;
```

allocates enough space for a single `ITEM*` and assigns the pointer to that space to `my_items`. Subsequently attempting to write to `my_items[i]` for any value of `i` other than 0 will overwrite random memory, which is -- to say the least -- undefined behaviour. Whatever other problems your code might have, you need to fix that before proceeding.

It's clear from the code that you expect to be able to store `num_choices + 1` `ITEM*`s in the array, so you need to allocate an array of at least that size.

```
my_items = new ITEM*[num_choices + 1];
```

(Really, you should replace the 6 in `my_items[6] = NULL;` with `num_choices`; otherwise, you have a bug waiting to bite you.)

Don't forget to use `delete[]` instead of `delete`, when you are done.

But since you are using C++, you might as well make use of it:

```
std::vector<ITEM*> my_items;
for (int x = 0; x < num_choices; x++) {
   my_items.emplace_back(new_item(choices[x], choices[x])); 
}
my_items.emplace_back(nullptr);
/* Unfortunately, new_menu requires a non-const ITEM**,
 * even though it should not modify the array. */
my_menu = new_menu(const_cast<ITEM**>(my_items.data()));
```

At the end, you still have to call `free_item` on each `ITEM*` before letting the `std::vector` destruct:

```
for (auto& item : my_items) free_item(item);
```

Comment: Thank you much, I feel dumb.